# I am getting "Stream specifier ' ' in filtergraph description" in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am generating 10 seconds of silence using an image. Here is my command

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 image.jpg -f lavfi -t 10 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" out.mp4
```

Also, I have tried

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 beach.jpg -f lavfi -t 10 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" out.mp4
```

I am getting following errors

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
Stream specifier '' in filtergraph description [0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 matches no streams.

ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 beach.jpg -f lavfi -t 10 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" out.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [0:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 matches no streams.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is missing the `-i` token for the image input, so it should be

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i image.jpg -f lavfi ...
```

However, for the actual task at hand, the concat filter is not required.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i image.jpg -f lavfi -t 10 -i anullsrc out.mp4
```

Comment: ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i beach.jpg -f lavfi -t 10 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" out.mp4

Comment: but still I get "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 2 on filter Parsed_concat_0"

Comment: Edited answer..

Comment: I need to use the complex filter as there are few more filters I am using in the pipeline, this was just part of it with multiple inputs.

Comment: Then you should have shown your actual command.